# Carousel doesn't work when Content Security Policy enabled

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, security, carousel, xss

I am using CSP and my Javascript carousel doesn't work, everything works but the carousel.
The carousels CSS is in another file and works, **the Java Script is in another file also but doesn't work.**

I have received no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your time.

**CSP:**

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css;
script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js;
script-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">`

**Carousel html:**

```
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="carousel carousel-showsixmoveone slide" id="carousel123">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active" ><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/bests/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div></div>
                            <div class="item"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/bests/7.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div></div>
                            <div class="item"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/bests/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div></div>
                            <div class="item"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/bests/7.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div></div>
                            <div class="item"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/bests/2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div></div>
                            <div class="item"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/bests/8.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div></div>
                            <div class="item"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/bests/9.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div></div>
                            <div class="item"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/bests/2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control">
                            <a href="#carousel123" data-slide="next"><img src="css/right.png"></a>
                            &nbsp;
                            &nbsp;
                            <a href="#carousel123" data-slide="prev"><img src="css/left.png"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JavaScript file**:

```
(function(){
    $('#carousel123').carousel({ interval: 2000 });
    $('#carouselABC').carousel({ interval: 3600 });
}());
(function(){
    $('.carousel-showsixmoveone .item').each(function(){
        var itemToClone = $(this);
        for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
            itemToClone = itemToClone.next();
            if (!itemToClone.length) {
                itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
           .addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
           .appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 3):

There cannot be multiple `script-src 'self'` in the code so the CSP meta will be like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css;
script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```